# Netcat only receiving first UDP packet from Scapy and Python

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I'm currently making a DNS tunnel in python using Scapy. I can send packets just fine (according to Wireshark). The problem is, when listening on Netcat on what I'm transmitting the dns packets to, I only receive the first packet.

I've heard that when binding, a UDP "connection" (for lack of better words) locks on a port, and drops all other packets from any other source port. However, I defined a source port, so I'm not sure what is going on.

```
def sendDns(incomingBytes):
    print('sending packet data :\n' + incomingBytes.decode('utf-8'))
    incomingBytes = base64.encodebytes(incomingBytes)
    send(IP(dst=dnsServer)/UDP(dport=53, sport=12345)/DNS(qd=DNSQR(qname=incomingBytes)))
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, I never fixed the problem, but the packets were received as desired in the python script I programmed (still not netcat). I'm still going to leave this unanswered for anyone who needs this fixed.